# Como setar valor em constante

Tags: react, dropzonejs

Estou usando o pacote react-dropzone para fazer upload de imgagens

Agora gostaria de após carregados os dados do servidor, gostaria de setar uma imagem que veio da busca de dados no react-dropzone

Como estou tentando:

```
const Banner = () => {
   const [ img1, setImg1 ] = useState()
   const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        titulo: '',
        subtitulo: '',
        descricao: '',
        slogan: ''
    })
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        api.get('/api/v1/banner/1')
           .then( response =>{
               setFormData( response.data )
               if( response.data.imagem1 != null ){
                   let string = `http://localhost:3001/foto/${response.data.imagem1}`
                   console.log('url', string);
                   
                   setImg1( string )
               }       
           })
    },[])

  return (
          <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="descricao">Imagem 1</label>
                        <Dropzone  onFileUploaded={setSelectedFile1} fileFromUrl={img1}/>
                    </div>
   )
}
```

Os dados carregam, mas a string é enviada para o dropzone através da função `fileFromUrl` é enviando antes de buscar os dados.

No dropzone estou tentando fazer assim:

```
const Dropzone = ( {onFileUploaded, fileFromUrl} ) =>{
    const [selectedFileUrl, setSelectedFileUrl] = useState('')
   
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log( 'dropzone', fileFromUrl);
        if( fileFromUrl != undefined ){
            
            setSelectedFileUrl( fileFromUrl )
        }
    },[])
```

Como faço para obter o valor da variável `fileFromUrl` dentro de dropzone e mostrar a imagem?

Comment: Não entendi!!!!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se eu entendi direito o seu problema... Aparentemente o valor do estado não está mudando porque o seu `useEffect` só executa quando o componente é montado, você precisa fazer com que ele execute quando o valor de `fileFromUrl` mudar.

**Exemplo**:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!!fileFromUrl) {
    setSelectedFileUrl(fileFromUrl);
  }
}, [fileFromUrl]);
```

Comment: Deu certo. Eu perguntei uma coisa, você resolveu duas rsrs

Obrigado!

Comment: Perfeito! Fico feliz em saber que deu certo.